# Shielded VM parameter on ClusterGenerator in Airflow Dataproc Operator using python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow

#### What do you see as an issue?

Here is the command i'm using to create the VM:

```py
CLUSTER_CONFIG = {
    "master_config": {
        "num_instances": 1,
        "machine_type_uri": "n1-standard-4",
        "disk_config": {"boot_disk_type": "pd-standard", "boot_disk_size_gb": 1024},
    },
    "worker_config": {
        "num_instances": 2,
        "machine_type_uri": "n1-standard-4",
        "disk_config": {"boot_disk_type": "pd-standard", "boot_disk_size_gb": 1024},
    },
}

create_cluster = DataprocCreateClusterOperator(
    task_id="create_cluster",
    project_id=PROJECT_ID,
    cluster_config=CLUSTER_CONFIG,
    region=REGION,
    cluster_name=CLUSTER_NAME,
)
```

And I'm following the document below:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/dataproc.html
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc.ClusterGenerator
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_modules/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc.html#ClusterGenerator

But I want to add the options of shielded VM, like the options below:

```py
{
  "enableSecureBoot": True,
  "enableVtpm": True,
  "enableIntegrityMonitoring": True
}
```

But i don't know which parameter I specify these options, and I need a help to solve this.

I've tried to put this on 'properties' parameter of ClusterGenerator, but this doesn't work.

Can someone help me?

I believe that if the documentation was more detailed, I could identify if my problem is the missing feature, seeing that I could help create this feature, but I cannot identify if this shielded vm parameter can be applied to the ClusterGenerator function

I've tried to put shieldedconfig on properties parameter, using a dicitionary like below:

```py
properties={
        "dataproc:dataproc.cluster.config.shielded_instance_config.enable_secure_boot": "false",
        "dataproc:dataproc.cluster.config.shielded_instance_config.enable_vtpm": "true",
        "dataproc:dataproc.cluster.config.shielded_instance_config.enable_integrity_monitoring": "true",
    },
```

And put directly like a parameter:

```py
shielded_instance_config={
        "enable_secure_boot": True,
        "enable_vtpm": True,
        "enable_integrity_monitoring": True,
    },
```